# missing FROM-clause entry for table. i dont know why

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
Select
         *
From 
    (select date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz) as "Week"
               ,Count(*) as "Total"
               ,count(*) filter (where status = 4) as "Success"
               ,count(*) filter (where status = 5) as "Failed"
        FROM kyc
        where created_date >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '5 weeks') 
          and created_date <  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        group by 1) as "T1"
INNER join

    (select date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz) as "Week"
               ,Count(*) as "Total"
               ,count(*) filter (where status = 4) as "Success"
               ,count(*) filter (where status = 5) as "Failed"
        FROM kyc
        where created_date >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '5 weeks') 
          and created_date <  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        group by 1) as "T2"
ON T1.Week = (T2.Week + interval '1 week');
```

and Error is **missing FROM-clause entry for table "t1" Position: 1047**

So why this happened and how to fix this

Comment: `T1` is a different name than `"T1"` - once you start using those dreaded double quotes you have to use them **everywhere**

Comment: Oh yes, i got it. tks you so much

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Isn't `T1` the same as `"t1"` (and as `t1`) though?

Comment: @Bergi: `T1` and `t1` and `"t1"` are the same: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS